# Node.JS Client App Simulating 1000/+ Client Connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to make a console based node.js application which simulates 1000/+ clients Connections to an existing node.js based TCP server app.

***Update:*** With the current version of this code^ I am getting an error `TypeError: cannot call method 'write' of undefined` at: `connx[connNos].Write(str)`. I guess I will have to rethink/rewrite this piece of code; any pointers are welcome.

Till now this is what I came up with but this doesn't work as implied:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 7000;
var timeout = 30000;

var connx = [];

for(var connNos = 0; connNos < 10; connNos++){

    connx[connNos] = net.createConnection(PORT,HOST);
    //connx.push(connx[connNos]);
    connx[connNos].on('connect', function(err){
        console.log('Client: Connected');
    });

    connx[connNos].on('error', function(data){
        console.log('>> ' + data);
    });

    connx[connNos].on('close', function(){
        console.log('Client: Conn Closed');

        process.exit();
    });

    process.stdin.on('data', function(data){
        console.log('sending data..');
        //connection.write(data);
        var str = "486229^4049^1018436^D^2013-04-01 00:02:09^22.715939100^88.374148220^27238^0^308^0^192.168.1.1^1^2013-04-01 19:49:04";
        connx[connNos].write(str);
        //connection.end();

    });

    process.stdin.resume();

}
```

Any help will be appreciated
TIA :D

Answer (score 3):

From the [doc](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener)

> net.createConnection(options, [connectionListener])#
>   Constructs a new socket object and opens the socket to the given location. When the socket is established, the 'connect' event will be emitted.
>
> For TCP sockets, **options argument should be an object** which specifies:
>
> port: Port the client should connect to (Required).
>   host: Host the client should connect to. Defaults to 'localhost'.
>   localAddress: Local interface to bind to for network connections.
>
> For UNIX domain sockets, **options argument should be an object** which specifies:
>
> path: Path the client should connect to (Required).

I guess

```
connx[connNos] = net.createConnection(PORT,HOST);
```

should be

```
connx[connNos] = net.createConnection({port:PORT,host: HOST});
```

Comment: Thx for replying. I think its better to restructure my code. Will post back :D

Answer (score 0):

Think async, most probably reason is that when you call socket.write socket connection was not estanblished. You should check connection before call or you can put code in connection listener.